# Concatenate two columns in CSV: Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
AuthorID    CityArrival CountryArrival  Departure   CountryDeparture    DateDeparture   DateArrival
1922    Paris   France  New York    UnitedState 2008-03-10  2001-02-02
1002    LosAngeles  UnitedState California  UnitedState 2008-03-10  2008-12-01
1901    Paris   France  Lagos   Nigeria 2001-03-05  2001-02-02
1922    Paris   France  NewYork UnitedState 2011-02-03  2008-12-01
1002    Paris   France  California  UnitedState 2003-03-04  2002-03-04
1099    Paris   France  Beijing China   2011-02-03  2009-02-04
1901    LosAngeles  UnitedState Paris   France  2001-03-05  2001-02-02
```

I want to concatenate `CityArrival` and `CountryArrival`.

Comment: You mean to combine them into one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['Arrival'] = df.CityArrival + ' ' + df.CountryArrival
```

Comment: AuthorID CityArrival CountryArrival Departure CountryDeparture DateDeparture DateArrival
1922 Paris France New York UnitedState 2008-03-10 2001-02-02
1002 LosAngeles UnitedState California  UnitedState 2008-03-10 2008-12-01
1901 Paris France Lagos Nigeria 2001-03-05 2001-02-02
1922 Paris France NewYork UnitedState 2011-02-03 2008-12-01
1002 Paris France California  UnitedState 2003-03-04 2002-03-04
1099 Paris France Beijing China 2011-02-03 2009-02-04
1901 LosAngeles UnitedState Paris France 2001-03-05 2001-02-02

Comment: import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')

df['Arrival'] = df.CityArrival + ' ' + df.CountryArrival
print df

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv    
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(path)
    for line in reader:
        arrival = "{}, {}".format(line['CityArrival'], line['CountryArrival'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have another question. From the "Arrival". I want to create dictionary using each value under the arrival (e.g. ParisFrance = { 2001-02-01:  [1922]}) so that date will be the key while any of the authorid that fall within the date will be added to the list.

Comment: Use collections.defaultdict for this.  You can initialize a dictionary like "travel_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))", then add values like "travel_dict["ParisFrance"]["2001-02-01"].append(1922)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['Arrival'] = df['CityArrival'].map(str) + ' ' + df['CountryArrival'].map(str)

# update file
df.to_csv('final.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Comment: Ty for `.map(str)` !